# Prevent Oracle indexes turn USABLE after INSERT

Tags: oracle

I have an interval partitioned table. I'd like to create a local index unusable by default to make all inserts work fast. I want manually turn indexes usable after insert. Currently every insert which creates new partition makes correspondend local index usable. How can I prevent it?

UPDATE: I'm working with Oracle 11.2

```
create table T (
   part integer
  ,nm   number
)
partition by range (part)
interval (1)
(partition empty values less than (1));

create index t_loc_idx on T (part, nm) local unusable 

insert into T
select 1, rownum from user_tables

insert into T
select 2, rownum from user_tables

select index_name, partition_name, status from user_ind_partitions 
where index_name = 'T_LOC_IDX'
```

What we can observe:

```
INDEX_NAME  PARTITION_NAME  STATUS
T_LOC_IDX   EMPTY           UNUSABLE
T_LOC_IDX   SYS_P8744       USABLE
T_LOC_IDX   SYS_P8745       USABLE
```

Answer (score 2):

Keep interval partition local indexes unusable by creating a partial index and setting `indexing off`:

```
create table T (
   part integer
  ,nm   number
)
partition by range (part)
interval (1)
(partition empty values less than (1))
INDEXING OFF /* <-- New */;

create index t_loc_idx on T (part, nm) INDEXING PARTIAL /* <-- New */ local unusable ;

insert into T
select 1, rownum from user_tables where rownum <= 10;

insert into T
select 2, rownum from user_tables where rownum <= 10;

select index_name, partition_name, status from user_ind_partitions 
where index_name = 'T_LOC_IDX';
```

New results:

```
INDEX_NAME   PARTITION_NAME   STATUS
==========   ==============   ======
T_LOC_IDX    EMPTY            UNUSABLE
T_LOC_IDX    SYS_P643         UNUSABLE
T_LOC_IDX    SYS_P644         UNUSABLE
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! What a nice solution, it will be very useful for lucky 12c users. I missed to say that the version I'm working with is 11.2, I will add this to main post.